# Netbeans connector requires reinstall every time - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, connector

I'm using chrome 44.0.2403.125 m and netbeans 8.0 (Build 201403101706). Every time I try to run my HTML file in netbeans it says I haven't installed the netbeans connector. When deleting and reinstalling it, through both webstore (latest version) and the .crx file in the netbeans folder, it works but when I close netbeans and chrome it has to be reinstalled again. Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to install all updates to NetBeans using Help->Check for updates from withing NetBeans. Maybe it was already fixed.

If it won't help, please file a bug against NetBeans [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=ide&component=Extbrowser) and please add output of

```
chrome://version/
```

opened in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem, **BUT** [*netbeans8.1 RC*](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/rc/) solves this problem.

The solution is to update your netbeans version.

My versions are:

- OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- Chrome: 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)
- NetBeans 8.1 RC (Build 201510012201)

It works like a charm... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this fix helped me:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254196

I post this here, since I found your question before I found solution on netbeans page.